# IRC webclient on normal webserver

Tags: javascript, web, irc

I want to set up a website which can do this:

The page itself should be blank or just a `connect` button.

While on the website I want to connect to an IRC server and listen for a specific command, which is given by a simple IRC message.

When receiving this command I want to play a short sound file that the command arrived.

This have to run in the webbrowser and should work on a normal webserver.

I already found something about node.js but this sounds like everything runs on the server itself, but this is what I don't want to have.

How can I do this? I know that I need javascript but I don't now where I could start.

I'd prefer some light open source projects I can modify a bit so there isn't much to do for me.

Comment: Sounds like you simply need websockets, an irc server, and a way to broadcast via websockets to the webrowser when the command happens in irc. You could replace websockets with longpolling, but i wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The IRC server is an existing one so I just have to read something about websockets?

Comment: websockets, and being able to read chat in irc from whatever your webserver (or websocket server) is. Could be as simple as an irc bot that logs all messages in a channel to a text file, however if you could somehow skip that step it would be more efficient.

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-irc Build a webserver and ircbot in one with node.js Starting to look like the task at hand will be relatively easy. Most of the work has been done for you.

Comment: But how can I run something like `node bot.js` on my webserver? Usually I just put my html / php file on and it works.

Comment: well, for one, you wouldn't use php if you were using node.js. If you wanted to integrate it with an existing php solution, you would need to either find a php way of doing it, or decide how you want to bring this functionality into the php page, be it by an iframe, or a JSONP/CORS Ajax request.

Comment: node.js can be executed by php, or it can completely replace php. The executed part would be less efficient because it would need to be executed over and over to get the information perodically, where as if you used node.js as the webserver it would be able to instantly broadcast the information.

Comment: But this still don't tell me how to run the node js stuff, or is it enough to put this on my webserver? I don't have a command line on this server to run this `node bot.js`

Comment: Then node.js is probably out of the question. Google php irc bot

Comment: I thought I need Javascript because this sound should play right after the command arrive, I don't want to refresh manually for the sound.

Comment: sorry, you don't have a choice. You need a server-side solution that will create an irc bot and listen for commands. client-side javascript can't do that.